# Am I being too technical and/or scientific while answering?

Tags: discussion

One of my friends was going after my TGO.SE profile yesterday. While he appreciated my answers and questions, he found it too much scientific and technical, specifically about physiology.

Am I answering too much scientific?

Examples:

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/5943/2303

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/4487/2303

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/8575/2303

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/7204/2303

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/6723/2303

https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/6478/2303

Comment: I'm new here, so I don't know exactly what's expected, but I looked at each of those answers, and I think they offer good information without being too technical. I like the way you use answers as teaching opportunities. Physiology's important in general for athletes, especially in the context of those questions. You don't appear to get off topic, and the number of votes seems to indicate that the community finds the information valuable. Please take into account that I'm not the right person to ask, but they look good to me.

Comment: @Sue: Thank you. I am glad that you find it useful and with necessary content. I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As everyone has different experiences I feel it is perfectly valid to answer questions in your own way.

You have experience in some of the more technical physiology aspects of the outdoors, and this is very useful to others, so please keep answering the way you do.

If you found you were consistently getting downvotes, I'd suggest having a look at your answers, but you get many upvotes.

In summary - your answers are fine :-)

Comment: Thanks a ton :-)

Comment: Agreed. The community will decide if the technical answer is actually useful-- it may not always be the best answer.